# Is there a quick way to see when a cell in a Google Sheets was last edited?

Tags: google-sheets, version-control

Google Sheets has a revision history accessible from File / See revision history. However, it doesn't appear to easily allow you to see **when** a particular part of the sheet (e.g. a cell) was changed? Is there an easy way to do this, short of clicking through every revision and seeing when that cell changes?

(Incidentally, I would consider this analogous to features such as [git blame](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-blame) from the [git](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Git_%28software%29) RCS).

Comment: I'll stick my neck out (yet!) again and say "No" - based on the deduction that if such existed then most of the many questions asking for a date stamp to be applied when a cell changes would not have been posted. However, that may be a "workaround" for you, ie take one of those scripts and apply it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This can now be accomplished via the [Show edit history feature](https://gsuiteupdates.googleblog.com/2019/06/edit-history-sheets.html). Right-click on a cell and select "Show edit history". It will show you who made the edit, when it was made, and what changed. You can then go back and forward through cell edits.

[image]

Comment: I love this feature for an individual cell. I want to compare an entire column between the version of a past date and the current version to see which cells changed. Do you know how I can do that?