# Is there an easy way to undo changes to a cell, column or sheet within a spreadsheet?

Tags: google-sheets

In Google Sheets, I may sometimes edit a cell, then edit another cell, and then decide that I want to undo the first edit.

Is that possible?

This also goes for rows, columns, sheets with a spreadsheet, ranges, etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, edits can be undone only in the reverse chronological order: most recent one, then the one before it, etc.

In the situation you described, the easiest solution is to undo the last two edits (Ctrl-Z twice), copy the cell or range of interest, redo the edits (Ctrl-Y twice), and paste back into that cell/range.

To go further in time, you can use revision history (accessed by clicking "all changes saved in Drive", or from the menu). One cannot copy directly from revision snapshots, but you can restore some revision, copy a range of cell, go back to latest revision (which is now second-latest) and paste.

Comment: Is there a way to at least view changes by sheet, row or column, so that I can manually make the necessary changes?

Comment: Not as far as I know. Spreadsheets are a far cry from version control software.

Comment: While edits can still only be undone in reverse chronological order, you can now view the edit history of a cell (not row or column) so that you can manually make the necessary change: https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/131938/164156