# Is there a non-coded way to pull last edit user and date into a cell?

Tags: google-sheets

Similar to the information as the solution found here. ([Is there a quick way to see when a cell in a Google Sheets was last edited?](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/73080/is-there-a-quick-way-to-see-when-a-cell-in-a-google-sheets-was-last-edited/131938#131938?newreg=40c3c23c822b496c994b54d9b9f44713)) I would like to populate a cell value with the User who edited the adjacent cell. Is it possible to do this without running code in the background? It seems the info is already present as you can right click and get the data.

Answer (score 1):

Tl;Dr: No

Unfortunately the docs usually only mentions the included features, not the missing ones.

Reference

- [Docs Editors Help](https://support.google.com/docs)